# Steam Woes! OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, nvidia, steam, opengl

I do realize this has been discussed before,and extensivly.  Problem is that software has updated, and therefore; the question has to.  My error..

OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems.

I tried as discussed before:

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

There lies the problem, them file removal solutions are outdated and they dont exist anymore.  Please help!  Steam is my life :/

Comment: Try checking in the /SteamApps/common/[game name]/bin/ folder for libstdc++.so.6  The only game that failed for me was Portal 2 and I had to delete this file out of a game-specific directory as listed above to get it to work.